# F# project is not supported for generating dependency graph?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, dependency-graph

I am using Visual Studio 2013, my solution contains both c# and f# projects. When I try to generate dependency graph for the solution, it only includes the C# projects. Is there a way to make sure the F# projects are also included? Or is there any other way to visualize the dependency in F# projects?

Comment: Trying it in VS2010 ultimate, I get them to come up in the dependency graph as an external dependency only (under Externals), not like the c#/vb ones.  Not sure if the same applies to 2013.

Comment: third-party tool NDepend works at the IL level which should mean you get dependency graphs across both C# and F# projects

Comment: As Phil mentioned, you can use a third-party tool. Also, please consider posting a suggestion to the Visual Studio User Voice page: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have a sln with C# and F# projects. Based on the comment by @tkarnau, I generated a dependency graph in VS2013, expanded the Externals group, dragged my own libraries outside of the Externals group, and collapsed the Externals group. This seems to only work partially. The F# projects that are not being referenced by other F# or C# project in my sln don't show up. For instance, a unit test project is not showing.